# While fasting, I take water into my mouth . How can I make sure that remaining water doesn't break my fast?

Tags: sawm

If you take water into your mouth for some reasons while fasting, how can you make sure that the remaining water in your mouth doesn't break your fast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try avoiding drink the remained water as far as you can. If you did, so the little quantity doesn't break your fast insha'Allah

Comment: Assalamu alaikum, welcome to Islam.SE, please consider adding some authentic references to your answer and make it trustworthy.

Answer (score 1):

IF you don't drink or eat anything **intentionally** your fast will not break.Sahih

> Al-Bukhari Hadith 8.662         Narrated by Abu Huraira
>
> The Prophet (saws) said, "If somebody eats something forgetfully while
>   he is fasting, then he should complete his fast, for Allah has made
>   him eat and drink."

Comment: Assalamu alaikum, welcome to Islam.SE, please consider adding some authentic references to your answer and make it trustworthy.